# Notational question on matrices, particularly in the context of differential geometry.

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I've seen the notation both in notes, and in for example Loring W. Tu:s book, the notation $a^j_i$ for a matrix-element in a matrix $$A = \Big\{a^i_j\Big\}_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$$ What is the row and what is the column here? I thought at first that the superscript was the row, but it does not seem to be the case. I am used to the notation $a_{ij}$ where i is the row and j is the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the index in the text (assuming you're looking at his *An Introduction to Manifolds*), that is the case.

> $B = [b^i _j]$ "Matrix whose $(i, j)$ entry is $b^i _j$ or $b_{ij}.$"

So in your case, that does indeed represent row $i$, column $j$.

Comment: I think I was looking at his other book, the one about chern-classes among other things. But his notation is very likely consistent between the books. :)